# Refresh Token is not update lastSignInDate

Tags: android, ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

After call getIDTokenForcingRefresh() or getIDToken() function, the Firebase User last sign-in date is not update, only with authenticate process.

After renew a token user, it would not should update that property ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refreshing the ID token does not change the sign-in date, only signing in does. So it sounds like the API is working as intended.

If this is not the behavior you get, edit your question to show the [minimal code that reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).